# Android share viewpager to other activity

Tags: java, android, listview, android-viewpager, singleton

I'm using a ViewPager element in my layout file. This ViewPager gets instantiated in my *MainActivity* class.

The ViewPager consists of two fragments: a listview and an ordinary view.

What I want however, is when the user touches an item on the listview, the ViewPager changes to the other fragment (the ordinary view).

Right now I have the ViewPager as an element in a singleton class. This way I can access it from both my *MainActivity* class and my *PostAdapter* (ListView adapter) class.

I'm not sure this is the correct approach though. Any thoughts? Thanks!

--EDIT
As requested, some code:

[MyProperties.java](http://pastebin.com/tjtV19Vb) (the singleton class)

[MainActivity.java](http://pastebin.com/1Tur4Nc7)

[PostAdapter.java](http://pastebin.com/MdVYCVEz)

Comment: Could you post please some of your code?

Comment: pass your ViewPager object to ListViewAdapter class? in constructor or other method

Comment: @Gianluca I've updated my post, containing the requested code

Comment: @Mac_Focha Isn't that about the same as using the singleton class? It's not really object oriented

Comment: Well singleton class isn't what You need in here, but simply passing the reference to Your ViewPager is just fine. You could pass other view in this laytout or the main container, your window's decor view etc but whats the point if you can simply pass the viewpager (and remember to null the reference later on when its not needed)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use static variable?

```
static ViewPager viewpager;
```

access it like following

```
MainActivity.viewpager.someThing();
```